# Footnote number line overflow

Tags: formatting, footnotes, typography

I am using a \footnote inside a list environment. Unfortunately the footnote number is causing a overfull \hbox:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this without changing the wording?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    ngerman,
    twoside,
    parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=155mm,paperheight=220mm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.1cm,bottom=2.1cm,includehead]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    babel=true,
    tracking=true,
    activate={true,nocompatibility},
    final,
    kerning=true,
    spacing=true,
]{microtype}

\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{compactitem}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[compactitem]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,leftmargin=.8cm}
\setlist[compactitem,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[compactitem,2]{label=---}
\setlist[compactitem,3]{label=*}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{294}

\subsection{Fazit}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{compactitem}
\item
  \emph{\ldots\ zu schweren (faktischen) Beschränkungen der
  Wirtschaftsfreiheit führt:} \blindtext
\item
  \emph{\ldots\ vollständig ausserhalb der Bereiche von
  Bedarfsverwaltung, Nebentätigkeit oder Randnutzung von
  Verwaltungsvermögen} statt"-fin"-det,\footnote{Vorstehend, Rz.~275.} wenn
  also etwa eine Behörde eine Software ohne jeden sachlichen
  Zusammenhang zu ihrer Tätigkeit entwickeln und veröffentlichen würde.
  In diesen Fällen wäre gestützt auf das Spezialitätsprinzip auf einer
  for"-mell-ge"-setz"-li"-chen Grundlage zu bestehen.
\end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

This behaviour disappears when you either delete the second \blindtext or the \emph (not the text inside) in the first \item.

Comment: Well, moving the footnote number to the next line would be no option. And apparently hyphenating 'stattfindet' would make the line under-full? You could use `microtype`. Note that it only makes sense to deal with these things at the very end of writing your document. Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your comment. I added a MWE.

Comment: Without changing the wording one option would be to reduce the leftmargin of the list.

Comment: There isn't much that you can do. stattfin-det looks ugly, statt-finded causes an under-full box. Try the `microtype` library. If you have at least 295 footnotes, changing the margin would probably introduce problems elsewhere. Maybe you can reduce the indentation of this particular list by a minuscule amount so that Ne-bentätigkeit goes to Neben-tätigkeit? (I have no idea about these german words, I just remember proper hyphenation from my classes.)